# Dates are not getting compared?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, android-date

I am comparing dates in my android application, how ever for my equal dates, `compareTo` or `equals` method returns me that dates are not equal. I have debugged through and I can see both my objects have same values. But some how it is not working. Following is the way I am doing it:

```
public static boolean compareDates(long deliveryTime, Date date) throws ParseException {

    Date deliveryDate = convertLongToDate(deliveryTime);
    deliveryDate.setHours(0);
    deliveryDate.setMinutes(0);
    deliveryDate.setSeconds(0);

    if (deliveryDate.equals(date))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

My `date` object does not contain `time`, so I am setting `deliverTime's` time to `0(zero)` as well, so that both objects can have same values. but it does not work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you post `convertLongToDate` method as well?

Comment: `equals()` is not appropriate here, extract `Year` and `Day of Year` from both dates and compare both.

Comment: By the way, Date is deprecated for long now and Calendar is the recommended replacement.

Comment: Print out the `getTime()` value of your two dates. I'm guessing they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a `Date` object out of the `deliveryTime`, and then compare the hours, minutes and seconds. A code is below.

```
public static boolean compareDates(long deliveryTime, Date date) {
  Date d = new Date(deliveryTime);
  return(d.getHours() == date.getHours() && d.getMinutes() == date.getMinutes() && d.getSeconds() == date.getSeconds());
}
```

Comment: it did the work for me. But I had to compare month, day and year in my case. However, you pointed me to right direction. Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to just compare `deliveryTime` to `date.getTime()` instead of converting `deliveryTime` to a Date?

### Edit

Since you didn't mention you want to ignore milliseconds, you could do:

```
(deliveryTime / 1000) == (date.getTime() / 1000)
```

That should strip out the milliseconds. Alternatively,

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(deliveryTime);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
//Clear out the other fields you don't care to compare
Date deliveryDate = c.getTime()
```

Comment: I tried that, but I am getting difference in miliseconds, however when I see value in date objects, those are same. how is it possible?

Comment: Its not possible. You must just have missed the milliseconds specified in the date. If you aren't concerned with milliseconds, you would need to strip those out as well. You would typically use the Calendar class for this. I'll update my answer with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you make `date` and `deliverydate` into `date objects`, then you can use

```
date.compareTo(deliveryDate);
```

This will return: `0` if the dates are the same, a value greater than 0 if date is more recent than `deliveryDate`, and a value less than 0 if date is before `deliveryDate`.

To get your dates into `date format`, you can use something like the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = sdf.parse(date);
        Date deliveryDate = sdf.parse(deliveryTime);
```